# How to check programmatically job cluster is unity catalog enabled or not in databricks

Tags: python, databricks, databricks-workflows

Is there any way to check job cluster is unity catalog enabled or not in databricks using python.

I tried with jobs api `https://{host_name}/api/2.0/jobs/get?job_id={job_id}`, but I didn't that cluster is unity catalog enabled or not.

Could anyone suggest how to get that programmatically, it would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this via [Get Job API](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/jobs/get).  Check following in the task's `new_cluster` or in the `job_clusters` following setting - `data_security_mode` it should be either:

- `SINGLE_USER` together with user ID in the `single_user_name` attribute for UC assigned clusters.
- `USER_ISOLATION` - for shared UC clusters.